# if is_page function not working for my PHP website

Tags: php

I am using if else conditional tag in my PHP website. My code is:

```
<?php if(is_page('print-systems-overview.php')) { ?>
<style type="text/css">
.activeNew{background:#4E4E4E;}
</style>
<?php } elseif (is_page('software.php')) { ?>
<style type="text/css">
.activeNew{background:grey;}
</style>
<?php } ?>
```

But I got fatal error:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_page() in D:\xampp\htdocs\project1234\header.php on line 36

After research on it I come to know that the is_page is working on wordpress only it is wordpress function and not working on core PHP. Is there any way to do this type of function in core PHP.

Please help me to fix this. I am new in PHP so not much knowledge about it. Thank

Rickky

Comment: What is `is_page()`? Have you created a function somewhere?

Comment: `is_page()` is Wordpress http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page - is it installed?

Comment: Thanks Darren and Fred
I come to know that is_page is wordpress function and we cant use it outside of wordpress. I didnt create is_page function in my site.

Is there anyway to do this type of thing in core PHP. I am very new in PHP. I only work in wordpress, there everything is ready made but  outside of it we have to create each function. 

Please let me know how can I do this type of thing in PHP. Its great help if you give me some example to do this type of query.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is page is `wordpress` function, if you wanted to create something like this in core php here is a way to do

Create a file to hold this function like `functions.php` so you can reuse it and include it in page

**functions.php**

```
<?php

function is_page($page_name) {
   $url = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
   //Check for current page equal to $page_name
   return basename($url) == $page_name;
}
```

and then check the page call it like

```
<?php include('functions.php') ?>

<?php if(is_page('print-systems-overview.php')) { ?>
<style type="text/css">
.activeNew{background:#4E4E4E;}
</style>
<?php } elseif (is_page('software.php')) { ?>
<style type="text/css">
.activeNew{background:grey;}
</style>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Saqueib, so I have to create file function.php and create this function there. Then I hope I can use above code(is_page function) in my pages. I will try it. Thanks again.

Comment: yes, define the above function and call it like you did, it will work

Comment: Hello Saqueib,  I create function in header file under script tag and then use above code in same header file but still it show same error on site...Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_page() in D:\xampp\htdocs\project1234\header.php

Comment: Now I use it on current page now activeNew class sytle use on all tabs. I want that style only come on current page not on all page. I use activeNew class on all tabs but I want styling like my code. But its not working... Class called but for all tabs

Comment: any good luck... I am still waiting if this issue solve... I really thanks if it is fixed  :)

Comment: my another developer friend solve it.<?php
function is_page($page_name) {
   $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
   //Check for current page equal to $page_name
   return stripos($url, $page_name);
}
?>   Now I use this code in function.php and doing some more tweaks and its working fine now. Thanks you all for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);` will return the current filename

```
function is_page(){
   $file_name = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
   if($file_name == 'print-systems-overview.php') { ?>
     <style type="text/css">
    .activeNew{background:#4E4E4E;}
     </style>                
   <?php } elseif ($file_name == 'software.php') { ?>
     <style type="text/css">
     .activeNew{background:grey;}
     </style>
   <?php }
 } ?>
```

just call the is_page() function

Comment: Hello Vidya, I use above function in fucntion.php file but nothing good come. show error, hope you will fix this error.....  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in D:\xampp\htdocs\project1234\function.php on line 4

Comment: Now error gone but nothing happen.. I use activeNew class for my tabs I want that tab color change when current page call. But class not called when I am in print-systems-overview.php page. Any idea what the issue behind it..?

Comment: Its not reusable, you need to use a function to check the current page, and decide what to do after that.

Comment: so what I use in the function to check the current page. Can you code it please??

Comment: @rickky I have already given the answer below, please try. its working i have checked, just include the `functions.php` above the all page and it will work, no need to change anything after that

Comment: @Sawueib 
So when I use code which you post above its call styling for all tabs. I only want to use style for current page where I am on it. My requirement is current page tab will be active and change the background color. Hope you understand my requirement. In our case my given styling is used to all tabs which is wrong.. Please let me know if you help me on it.. Thanks